# Navigating between tabs and View - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Im fairly new to programming. I'm simply having a problem with trying to create the correct code to a navigate tab on the menu on the application. I, have been try for hours to figure out what the error in the coding in to navigate simply to a tab

app.js

```
.state('tab.list', {
url: '/list',
views: {
'tab-list': {
templateUrl: 'templates/timeline/tab-list.html',
controller: 'ListCtrl', 
}
}
})
```

tab-list.html

```
<ion-view view-title="List">
<ion-content>
<ion-list>
<ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="chat in chats" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/chats/{{chat.id}}">
<img ng-src="{{chat.face}}">
<i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
<ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="remove(chat)">
<p class="padding center" style="margin: 20px 0px">
To test how thi
</p>
</ion-option-button>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Tabs.html

```
<ion-tab title="List" icon-off="ion-ios-people-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-play" href="#/tab/list">
<ion-nav-view name="tab-list"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

Controller-list.js

```
.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, ListCtrl) {
   });
```

Comment: please tell us what is happening and what is your desired result

Comment: my desired result is simply to just display a page using the navigation tab menu. At the moment it is blank the page when navigating

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: I don't no if there is. Im unsure if the code itself is right. It maybe wrong. It needs correcting